# PowerBuilder - Different encoding PB 6.5 - PB 10.5

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, powerbuilder

I have built an encryption function for an application in PB 6.5, it works fine, it takes the data of a person, encrypts it and stores the resulting string in the database. In the other hand, I have access to this data in an application built in PB 10.5 (because both application share the database).

The problem is I cannot recover the data correctly :(
I googled it and I have read some documentation. I know PB6.5 uses ANSI codification and PB10.5 uses UTF-16LE, so I have tried the functions I found in the documentation to see what I get:

```
lb_text = Blob(original_string, EncodingANSI!)
ls_string1 = String(lb_text, EncodingANSI!)
ls_string2 = String(lb_text, EncodingUTF16LE! )
```

ls_string1 gave me a string that is very similar to the original string encoded with PB6.5 and ls_string2 gave me a string that is a sequence of the 'square character': 㔐

My question is:

**Is there a way to standardize the encoding between diferents versions of PB?** or...

**Is there a function (in PB10.5) to convert a string to the encoding I need?**

Comment: Standardize: no. Function: ummm.. String (..., EncodingANSI!)? Maybe there's something missing from your explanation of the problem, because it sounds like you have the solution. Let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my encrypting function: I used a string (ascii_string) with [ASCII](http://www.ascii.cl/es/) characters from 1 to 255 to encode the data, but I found there are 'strange' characters in positions 1 until 31.

So, in PB6.5 I did:

```
for i=32 to 255
   ascii_string += string(char(i))
next
```

and for PB 10.5:

```
for i=32 to 256
  aux = Blob(char(i))
  ascii_string += String(aux, EncodingANSI!)
next
```

and it works for each versions!